# Export Crystal report to PDF from CrystalReportViewer button (using Asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I have an ASP.net web application in C#.

The export button and the print button in the toolbar is not working.

When I click on Print/Export button, dialogue box appear which have option to select pages or select format then i click on export button no file download or save.

```
paramField.Name = "@GatePass";

paramDiscreteValue.Value = GPLabel.Text;
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);
CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("DO_Report.rpt"));
reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Admin1");

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

I have tried exporttodisk code as well like,

```
reportdocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel,"C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ashar.pdf");
```

but this code just export the blank report on given destination, i already tried 
(ExportToHttpResponse) but no solution found,
help me please 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting it as a memory stream maybe. Also I think there's a printToPrinter method on ReportDocument

Answer (score 0):

I found this on SAP site.  Because the export does a postback, you have to save the session information:

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

        report.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/Reports/MyReport.rpt"));
        report.SetDatabaseLogon("User", "Password", "server", "database");
        Session.Add("u201Creportu201D", report);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
    }
    else
    {
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Session["u201Creportu201D"];
    }
```

https://answers.sap.com/questions/6790184/reportdocumentsetdatabaselogon-not-working-on-dril.html